# How do I get parameter value from arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google

I am trying to pass parameter value from google actions to my fulfillment.
However, I am not able to get only the parameter value. How should I able to get only "Asda" under `newName` field from the argument?  Do I have to extract it from `conv` (like `conv.inputs.arguments[1].rawText`)? if like this, then what is the purpose of having a name for the parameter?

Request JSON from Google Actions:

```
{
  "user": {
    "userId": "ABwppHEAPgcgb2yFUFURYFEJGg4VdAVcL9UKO9cS7a7rVfAMr9ht67LzgrmMseTvb5mmJjbjj7UV",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "lastSeen": "2018-05-15T01:08:55Z",
    "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationId": "1526346570079",
    "type": "NEW"
  },
  "inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "com.example.test.RENAME",
      "rawInputs": [
        {
          "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
          "query": "Talk to GoTestApp to rename Asda"
        }
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "name": "trigger_query",
          "rawText": "rename Asda",
          "textValue": "rename Asda"
        },
        {
          "name": "newName",
          "rawText": "Asda",
          "textValue": "Asda"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "surface": {
    "capabilities": [
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
      }
    ]
  },
  "isInSandbox": true,
  "availableSurfaces": [
    {
      "capabilities": [
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My code of Fulfillment side:

```
app.intent('com.example.test.RENAME', (conv, input, arg) => {
  console.log(input); //print Talk to GoTestApp to rename Asda
  console.log(arg); //only print "rename Asda"
  console.log(arg[1]) //only print "e"
}
```

Action Package action:

```
  "name": "RENAME",
  "intent": {
    "name": "com.example.test.RENAME",
    "parameters": [{
      "name": "newName",
      "type": "SchemaOrg_Text"
    }],
    "trigger": {
      "queryPatterns": [
        "rename $SchemaOrg_Text:newName"
      ]
    }
  },
  "fulfillment": {
    "conversationName": "example"
  }
}
```

Comment: if you write `(conv, input, arg1, arg2)` - what's arg2?

Comment: or `(conv, input, ...arg)` - now, what's `arg[1]`

Comment: arg2 is undefined, arg[1] is character 'e'

Comment: oh, doesn't work like I thought it did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to get an [Actions SDK argument](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Argument) by name, which then you can use:

```es6
const newName = conv.arguments.get('newName')
```

This will return the `rawText` of the argument.

Argument retrieval is pretty complicated so there's actually 4 ways to retrieve arguments either by name or by list.

[`conv.arguments.get`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_argument.arguments.html#get) (which is a shortcut for `conv.arguments.parsed.get`) will get an argument by name returning the inferred property excluding `name` and `status` and returning `textValue` with last priority.

`conv.arguments.status.get` can be used to get a `status` argument by name.

The most common use case is when there is only one argument, so there's a shortcut for retrieving the **single** argument via the intent handler like you mentioned.

```es6
app.intent('intent.name', (conv, input, arg, status) => {
  console.log(arg); // print the parsed single argument like `rawText` if exists
  console.log(status) // print the single argument status if exists
}
```

To get the raw argument by name without doing any inferred parsing, you can use `conv.arguments.raw.get`. Then you can manually extract out the properties like `rawText` or `textValue` yourself.

With each of these getters for arguments, there's a corresponding way to retrieve by order with an array: `conv.arguments.parsed.list`, `conv.arguments.status.list`, and `conv.arguments.raw.list`.

`conv.arguments` is also iterable for raw values, so if you want to loop through the raw arguments, just do:

```es6
for (const arg of conv.arguments) {
  const value = arg.rawText;
}
```

Comment: it works.  Now I have more understanding of it. Thanks for detail explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'newName' is a parameter defined in dialogflow, then you can easily access it with conv like this:

```
let newN = conv.parameters['newName'];
```

Comment: 'newName' is the value for 'name' parameter under arguments.

Comment: it gives me error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'newName' of undefined"

Comment: In the brackets you should put your parameter name, it can be the 'name' you mentioned. Otherwise you just print somewhere conv.parameters and you will see an array with all your parameters.