# How to get the original value of the parameters that the user enters( after it has been parsed)

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am not able to get the original value of the parameter that has been matched with the entity. I already have an output context and I can see the entity.original value in the request json, but I am not able to get the value.  I have tried the methods this post ([How do I get parameter value from arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341054/how-do-i-get-parameter-value-from-arguments)) and this post ([DialogFlow - Get original string associated with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54678897/dialogflow-get-original-string-associated-with-parameter?source=post_page)) mentioned.But none seem to work. They simply return the entity name or undefined. Any help is appreciated.

Here is a part of the Request JSON

```
"outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/XXXXXXX/agent/sessions/XXXX/contexts/office",
        "lifespanCount": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "name": [
            "name"
          ],
          "name.original": [
            "scott"
          ]
        }
          },
```

I want to get the "name.original" value.

Comment: Figured it out: let value = conv.contexts.input.${"_input-context's name_"}.parameters[""matched_parameters_name".original"]; Which still seems like a cumbersome way. If there is any other way to find out the value. Do tell. Thank you –

Comment: There is another hack, where instead of input context you can put this.      let value = conv.contexts.input.actions_capability_screen_output.parameters['"matched_parameters_name"'formNames.original'];

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is within dialogflow, add a new parameter that has a value of the name of the parameter you want the original text of, and add .original.

Now when ever you want let's say date.original, you simply request originalDate.

[image: Dialogflow actions and parameter]

Comment: How to do this via Fulfilment